# Elasticsearch turn wrong results?

Tags: elasticsearch

i am try build an search system like amazon ( suggest categories from included products search terms ) i am querying with AND operator but elasticsearch turn me wrong results, that categories doesnt linked with this product.

Here is my maps.

```
 $params = [
        'index' => $index,
        'body' => [
            'settings' => [
                "analysis" => [
                    'filter' => [

                        'autocomplete_filter' => [
                            'type' => 'edge_ngram',
                            'min_gram' => '2',
                            'max_gram' => '10'
                        ]
                        ,
                        'shingle' => [
                            'type' => 'shingle',
                            'min_shingle_size' => '3',
                            'max_shingle_size' => '3'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'analyzer' => [

                        'autocomplete' => [
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                            'filter' => [
                                'lowercase',
                                'autocomplete_filter'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'trigram' => [
                            'type' => 'custom',
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                            'filter' => [
                                'lowercase',
                                'shingle'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'reverse' => [
                            'type' => 'custom',
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                            'filter' => [
                                'lowercase',
                                'reverse'
                            ]

                        ]

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ];

    $params = [
                'index' => $index,
                'type' => $type,
                'body' => [
                    $type => [
                        '_source' => [
                            'enabled' => true
                        ],
                        'properties' => [
                            'search' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'fielddata' => true,
                                'fields' => [
                                    'auto_complete' => [
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
                                        'fielddata' => true
                                    ],
                                    'suggestions' => [
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'analyzer' => 'trigram',

                                    ],
                                    'trigram' => [
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'analyzer' => 'trigram',

                                    ],
                                    'reverse' => [
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'analyzer' => 'reverse',

                                    ],


                                ]
                            ],
                            'name' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',

                            ],

                            'category_id' => [
                                'type' => 'integer'
                            ],

                            'category' => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'fielddata' => true

                            ],

                            'price' => [
                                'type' => 'float',
                            ]

                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'include_type_name' => true
            ];
```

An here is my search query

```
$params = [
        'index' => $index,
        'type' => $type,
        'body' => [
            //'from' => $from,
            'size' => '20',//$item_per_page,
            //"_source" => ["category", "category_id", "brand", "brand_id"],
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query' => $search,
                            'fields' => [
                                'search.auto_complete^5'
                            ],
                            "fuzziness" => "AUTO",
                            "prefix_length" => '3',
                            'type' => 'best_fields',
                            'operator' => 'AND',

                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'suggest' => [
                'text' => $search,
                'suggestion' => [
                    'phrase' => [
                        'field' => 'search.trigram',
                        'size' => '1',
                        'gram_size' => '3',
                        'direct_generator' => [
                            [
                                'field' => 'search.trigram',
                                'suggest_mode' => 'always'

                            ]
                        ],
                        'highlight' => [
                            'pre_tag' => '<em>',
                            'post_tag' => '</em>'
                        ]
                    ]


                ]
            ],
            'aggs' => [
                'by_category' => [
                    'terms' => [
                        'field' => 'category_id',
                        'order' => [
                            '_count' => 'desc'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'aggs' => [
                        'category_name' => [
                            'top_hits' => [
                                'size' => '1',
                                '_source' => [
                                    'include' => ['category']
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Its looking getting some results, someones correct someones wrong.

for eg: I have **Loreal Hair color oxidant** linked **oxidants category** when i search loreal oxidants
show me oxidants category and show also different categories, also if i write wrong loreal ocidants its offer me loreal oxidants but, keeping search just correct words. a try a lot of mapping combinations, result all time same. cany one can help me ?

Comment: please choose a more specific title.

Comment: its product title. but whats the problem ?